# Droning on and on

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Should [drone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone) and [drone.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone.io) both exist? They appear to be describing exactly the same thing...

Comment: Because it is 2016, if this were a burninating request, we could use `Drone [drone]`.