# Merge [drone] and [drone.io] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [drone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone) and [drone.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone.io) tags cover the same [Drone](https://drone.io/) CI system - the [drone.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone.io) tag was specifically created for this system.

From a quick scan of [drone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone), it is clear that the vast majority  of answers tagged [drone] are about Drone CI, not flying drones.

### Earlier proposals

The author of Drone, [Brad Rydzewski](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160454/brad-rydzewski), would prefer a single tag as he mentioned in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332220/proposal-create-the-tags-drone-ci-or-drone-io-instead-drone).

Also suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314864/droning-on-and-on) in less specific way - creating new question as this is a more specific request.

### *(Dropped) A. Making [drone] into synonym of [drone.io]*

In this option, we merge [drone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone) into [drone.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone.io), which is more specific, i.e. make [drone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone) a synonym of [drone.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone.io)

- there are some questions about flying drones under [drone] but nothing under [drone.io].

### B. Using a 'flying drone' tag alongside [drone.io]

In this option, we use [flying-drone] as the tag for flying drones, and [drone.io] for Drone CI.

We could make [drone] a synonym of either [flying-drone] or [drone.io]:

- Given that Drone CI is by far the most popular meaning in the [drone]-tagged answers, I think [drone] should be a synonym of [drone.io], if there is a synonym
- Alternatively, we could have no [drone] tag, so that people use the more specific [flying-drone] or [drone.io]

### Re-tagging

Is there a relatively easy way to migrate the [drone] tagged questions to [drone.io], then manually retag any flying-drone ones to the new [drone-aerial] tag?

Comment: Having myself never heard of drone.io (but heard plenty about drones of the flying sort), I wouldn't think `drone` should map to `drone.io`.  Though if `drone.io` is popular enough to create common confusion while tagging, then seems the plain `drone` can be nixed (pointing to whatever tag disambiguation mechanism there is) and some other tag used.   Something like `flying-drone` seems less stilted than `drone-aerial`.

Comment: @HostileFork I'm fine with option B with no [drone] tag - is there some way to stop the [drone] tag from being created? Also, there are already lots of Drone CI questions under [drone] - how can those those be re-tagged in bulk onto [drone.io]?  I would be OK with manually re-tagging the flying-drone questions onto [flying-drone] as there aren't too many.

Comment: Powers-that-be have mass bulk retagging tools that don't require manual editing, which is a reason for bringing tag requests up on meta.  So if the outcome of this discussion is to do that retag...and you manually change the flying-drone ones...the rest would be done by one of those people, once enough attention is attracted to the issue.

Comment: @HostileFork - what's the next step to move this forward?

Comment: Attract the attention of powers-that-be, I guess? It used to be you could bounty questions on meta, but no longer.  You might reach out to the drone.io community who have SO accounts and get them to upvote this, and get someone who has a stronger opinion on what *the answer is* than I do.  Also might ask about it in [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)

Comment: Is "flying-drone" really a tag that is on topic? I mean that yes, there is programming that occurs for drones to fly, but shouldn't the tags on such a question be about the languages, and not the flying thing? If we're creating on-board software for a refrigerator, would we tag with "refrigerator"?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's a fair point, but there are other tags such as [robot] and [smartphone] which relate to things that are programmed rather than the technologies used to program them.  I wouldn't want to see many such tags, but having [flying-drone] would help divert such questions away from the [drone.io] tag.  If we don't have a [flying-drone] tag, we should not have a [drone] tag in order to avoid confusing the two topics.

Comment: What about underwater drones?

Answer (score 2):

What do we need to do to make this happen[.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405622/merge-or-synonimize-drone-io-tag-with-drone-and-droneci-tags?noredirect=1#comment828047_405622)

The description for the [drone.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone.io) tag is

> Drone is a hosted continuous integration service. It enables you to conveniently set up projects to automatically build, test, and deploy as you make changes to your code.

The less popular, but still somewhat frequently used [drone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone) tag has the following description:

> Drone is a Continuous Integration platform built on Docker, written in Go

And lastly, the rarely used tag [droneci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/droneci) does not include a description.

Having all three is needlessly confusing, as can be seen by the amount of questions referencing drone under each tag[.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405622/merge-or-synonimize-drone-io-tag-with-drone-and-droneci-tags)

Comment: That description is a direct copy from https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/integration/ci/drone.html. It should be rewritten to be less marketing-speak and more about how to use the tag.