# Merge or synonimize [drone.io] tag with [drone] and [droneci] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Drone.io is a CI platform.

The description for the [drone.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone.io) tag is

> Drone is a hosted continuous integration service. It enables you to conveniently set up projects to automatically build, test, and deploy as you make changes to your code.

The less popular, but still somewhat frequently used [drone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drone) tag has the following description:

> Drone is a Continuous Integration platform built on Docker, written in Go

And lastly, the rarely used tag [droneci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/droneci) does not include a description.

Previous discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376451/merge-drone-and-drone-io-tags), though no action was taken and as a result

Comment: There's no need to post duplicate requests. If you want the other post to gain traction, you can always post an answer on that instead.

Comment: Is that the best way to gain traction? I'm worried 2.5 years from now someone else will be posting another follow up.

Comment: Yep, that's the best way. True, things haven't been moving forward on the tags side as quickly as before, as I've been very busy for a while. Hopefully, things soon clear up and I'll get more time to focus on tags.